# Using TextEditingController live changes in Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textinputfield

I am learning Flutter and trying now to monitor the changes on a `TextEditingController`. I can **monitor** it, using a listener function, but I cannot use the variable in a `Text` widget:

```dart
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  var _textName = "";
  final _textNameController = TextEditingController();

  void _nameChanged() {
    _textName = _textNameController.text;
    print(
        "text controller changed to '${_textNameController.text}' ($_textName)");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textNameController.addListener(_nameChanged);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textNameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.ac_unit,
                size: 50,
              ),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _textNameController,
              // onChanged: (value) {
              //   _textName = _textNameController.text;
              // },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'description',
              ),
            ),
            Text("text is ${_textName}"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried, as you can see, using a listener and changing the value of a variable, then using the variable in the `Text` field. Then using an `onChanged` function. No changes in the `Text` widget except when I make a change in the source code and flutter hot reloads. It seems like the `Text` is constant, but how?

The output strings of the listener show the correct strings, though.

How can I see live-changing the `Text` field, using the `TextEditingController`? What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setState` to update the ui.

```dart
  void _nameChanged() {
    _textName = _textNameController.text;
    print(
        "text controller changed to '${_textNameController.text}' ($_textName)");

    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: Aw man, what an embarassing rookie error... I must have been too tired, I was adamant I had `SetState` there...

Comment: sometime it happens to all. dont worry